# ruby on rails command equal to data retrieved by this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone say the equivalent command for below query to retrieve in ruby on rails controller

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.principal NOT IN (SELECT principal FROM table2)
```

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: E.g. `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.principal NOT IN (SELECT principal FROM table2)"`.

Comment: Have a look at the Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) come back when this does not help and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that

```
Table1.where.not(principal: Table2.pluck(:principal))
```

Comment: Use `#pluck` instead of `all.map`, also you can use `where.not` instead of SQL fragment.

Comment: @pascalbetz thanks for the suggestions , i updated the answer.

Comment: Since you have gone with `where.not` I would caveat that with rails > 5 and add back in the sql fragment for lower versions. It makes this answer more complete in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Table1.where(["principal not in (?)",Table2.select(:principal)])
```